# Embedded C, Bootloader configuration for PIC32MX795F512L

Tags: bootloader, pic32

In MPLAB, I need to use bootloader for  PIC32MX795F512L. I am able to program boot section into  kseg boot memory till 0x8fc00000 and application code into kseg0_program_mem at 0x9d000000. I can jump from bootloader to application using jump to addr command but I am facing problem while jumping from application to bootloader. I have tried with jump to addr (bootloader address) but it won't work. Please assist me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a reset command, it will set you back to the processor start address. Check the POR bits for a SW reset to see if you caused the reset or if the board was just powered on.

Comment: Checked same procedure. But its not getting reset to bootloader address

Comment: use: asm("reset"); and in the bootloader check if(RCONbits.SWR) /* I triggered bootloader */

Answer (score 0):

I found this in one of the many pdf's for my PIC32MX270, I believe it's consistent for the whole PIC32MX family:

```
/* The following code illustrates a software Reset */
// assume interrupts are disabled
// assume the DMA controller is suspended
// assume the device is locked
/* perform a system unlock sequence */
// starting critical sequence
SYSKEY = 0x00000000; //write invalid key to force lock
SYSKEY = 0xAA996655; //write key1 to SYSKEY
SYSKEY = 0x556699AA; //write key2 to SYSKEY
// OSCCON is now unlocked
/* set SWRST bit to arm reset */
RSWRSTSET = 1;
/* read RSWRST register to trigger reset */
_excep_code = RSWRST;
/* prevent any unwanted code execution until reset occurs*/
while(1);
```

The while(1) will also lock up the uC so that the watchdog should reset the device if all else fails.  I've got this code in my exception handler too (system_exceptions.c if you are using Harmony), that way when something goes wonky (DMA disaster or you try to sprintf(foo_string, "%f", NAN)), the device will reset instead of becoming a paperweight.